# pandas datetime doesn't convert the dates properly in python

Tags: python, pandas

i have a dataframe data

```
d=pd.DataFrame({"dat":["01-06-68", "01-06-57","14-02-80","01-01-04","07-11-20"],
                "j":[34,2,1,7,8]})
```

i want to convert the dat column to "YYYY-MM-DD" format which is currently in dd-mm-yy format

**Code using**

```
pd.to_datetime(d.dat)
```

The output of this is coming out to be wrong

```
0   2068-01-06
1   2057-01-06
2   1980-02-14
3   2004-01-01
4   2020-07-11
Name: dat, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Problems

1. it was supposed to be giving output year as 1968 and not 2068
2. Months and date are also not coming in proper order

Required Output:

```
    0   1968-06-01
    1   1957-06-01
    2   1980-02-14
    3   2004-01-01
    4   2020-11-07
    Name: dat, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: I think you should fill in the missing numbers for the year. Else how would you distinguish 1920 from 2020? Make a little function to rewrite the data in the proper format, then apply it to the column.

Comment: The data I am working with is huge hence inserting or filling won't be an appropriate solution I feel .@alec_djinn

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution with replace in callable for test last digits and then use `%Y` for match years in YYYY format:

```
f = lambda x: '19' + x.group() if int(x.group()) > 22 else '20' + x.group()
d.dat = d.dat.str.replace('(\d+)$', f, regex=True)
d.dat = pd.to_datetime(d.dat, format='%d-%m-%Y')

print (d)
         dat   j
0 1968-06-01  34
1 1957-06-01   2
2 1980-02-14   1
3 2004-01-01   7
4 2020-11-07   8
```

Or subtract 100 years if year greater like `2022`:

```
d.dat = pd.to_datetime(d.dat, format='%d-%m-%y')

d.dat = d.dat.mask(d.dat.dt.year.gt(2022), d.dat - pd.offsets.DateOffset(years=100))
print (d)

         dat   j
0 1968-06-01  34
1 1957-06-01   2
2 1980-02-14   1
3 2004-01-01   7
4 2020-11-07   8
```

Comment: wow, this is a great solution using `mask` and `gt`

Comment: months and date are not in the proper order is also one of the issue.. i ll edit  the question and put this also

Comment: Hey @jezrael i think i found the solution for mismatching months as date also please update the answer accordingly

Comment: d.dat = pd.to_datetime( d.dat.apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, "%d-%m-%y").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")) )
d.dat = d.dat.mask(d.dat.dt.year.gt(2021), d.dat - pd.offsets.DateOffset(years=100))
d